# How to load Internal CSS and fix classes removed in mobile view for email template in gmail

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have developed a responsive email template. This template is working fine in outlook web and outlook app. But Gmail web and Gmail internal CSS and classes are removed automatically.
To hide the pre-header in mobile I tried [to hide preheader in mobile for gmail](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/889-hide-show-td-in-gmail-outlook-yahoo?fbclid=IwAR2gsBs8OVdVCnWGS_t3R4FQlKgI-W9-W6rHuJczoeoZEDNyN6hy-RS4ebc).

Please, anyone, help me to fix automatically removed classes and internal CSS issues.
[Email desktop design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsC1y.png)
[Email template mobile deisgn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HasNV.png)

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
   xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
   <head>
     
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
      <!-- Forcing initial-scale shouldn't be necessary -->
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
      <title>Forgot Password Emailer</title>         
      <style type="text/css">
         *,
         body,
         img {
         padding: 0;
         margin: 0;
         }
         reset-btnn {
         padding: 100px;
         }
         body {
         width: 100% !important;
         min-width: 100%;
         -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
         -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
         }
         .ExternalClass {
         width: 100%;
         }
         .no-underline {
         text-decoration: none !important;
         }            
        
         body {
         font-size: 16px;
         height: 100% !important;
         font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
         }
          {
         -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
         -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
         }
        
         table,
         td {
         mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
         mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
         }
        
         table {
         border-collapse: collapse;
         table-layout: fixed;
         margin: 0 auto;
         border-spacing: 0 !important;
         }
         td {
         word-wrap: break-word;
         border-collapse: collapse !important;
         }
         table,
         tr,
         td {
         padding: 0;
         vertical-align: top;
         }
       
         img {
         outline: none;
         border: 0 !important;
         text-decoration: none;
         -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
         width: auto;
         max-width: 100%;
         clear: both;
         height: auto;
         }
         a img {
         border: none;
         }
         td u {
         color: #454545;
         }
         #main_table {
         width: 600px !important;
         margin: 0 auto;
         }
        
         @media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
         .mobscale {
         width: 100% !important;
         }
         .res_img {
         width: 100% !important;
         height: auto !important;
         }
         #main_table {
         width: 100% !important;
         margin: 0 auto;
         }
         .no-break,
         .pre-header {
         display: none !important;
         }
         .mobshow,
         * [lang~="x-mobshow"] {
         display: block !important;
         width: 100% !important;
         width: auto !important;
         max-height: inherit !important;
         overflow: visible !important;
         float: none !important
         }
         .mobhide,
         * [lang~="x-mobhide"] {
         display: none !important
         }
         .no-break,
         .pre-header {
         display: none !important;
         }
         .mobtxtcenter {
         text-align: center !important
         }
         .mobtxtjustify {
         text-align: justify !important
         }
         .mob_width_5 {
         width: 5% !important;
         }
         .mob_width_95 {
         width: 95% !important;
         }
         .mob_width_15 {
         width: 15% !important;
         }
         .mob_width_70 {
         width: 70% !important;
         }
         .img_width_cls {
         width: 140px !important;
         }
         .full_width {
         width: 100% !important;
         display: block !important;
         }
         .img_center,
         .center_img {
         margin: 0 auto;
         text-align: center;
         display: block;
         }
         }
         @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
         body {
         -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
         }
         .mobscale {
         width: 100% !important;
         }
         .res_img {
         width: 100% !important;
         height: auto !important;
         }
         #main_table {
         width: 100% !important;
         margin: 0 auto;
         }
         .no-break {
         display: none !important;
         }
         .mobshow,
         * [lang~="x-mobshow"] {
         display: block !important;
         width: 100% !important;
         width: auto !important;
         max-height: inherit !important;
         overflow: visible !important;
         float: none !important
         }
         .mobhide,
         * [lang~="x-mobhide"] {
         display: none !important
         }
         .no-break {
         display: none !important;
         }
         .mobtxtcenter {
         text-align: center !important
         }
         .mobtxtjustify {
         text-align: justify !important
         }
         .full_width {
         width: 100% !important;
         display: block !important;
         }
         .img_center,
         .center_img {
         margin: 0 auto;
         text-align: center;
         display: block;
         }
         .mob_width_5 {
         width: 5% !important;
         }
         .mob_width_95 {
         width: 95% !important;
         }
         .mob_width_15 {
         width: 15% !important;
         }
         .mob_width_70 {
         width: 70% !important;
         }
         .img_width_cls {
         width: 140px !important;
         }
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-color:#ccc;">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <!--[if (gte mso 9)]>
                  <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                           <![endif]-->
                           <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="main_table" align="center"
                              style="max-width:600px; margin:auto; table-layout: fixed; vertical-align:top; background-color:#fff">
                              <tbody>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>
                                       <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="pre-header">
                                          <tr>
                                             <td width="3%" align="left" class="mob_width_15"></td>
                                             <td width="90%" align="left" class="mob_width_70">
                                                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                   <tr>
                                                      <td>
                                                         <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left"
                                                            class="mobscale">
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <td height="20" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px">&nbsp;
                                                               </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <td
                                                                  style="color: #3a4143;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 20px;text-align: left;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;mso-line-height-alt: 20px;font-weight: bold">
                                                                  FORGOT PASSWORD
                                                               </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <td
                                                                  style="color: #3a4143;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 20px;text-align: left;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;mso-line-height-alt: 20px;font-weight: bold"
                                                                  class="link_disable">
                                                                  From: [From]
                                                               </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <td
                                                                  style="color: #3a4143;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 20px;text-align: left;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;mso-line-height-alt: 20px;font-weight: bold">
                                                                  Recipient: [FirstName] [[To]] 
                                                               </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <td
                                                                  style="color: #3a4143;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 20px;text-align: left;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;mso-line-height-alt: 20px;font-weight: bold">
                                                                  Subject Line: Subject
                                                               </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <td
                                                                  style="color: #3a4143;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 20px;text-align: left;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;mso-line-height-alt: 20px;font-weight: bold">
                                                                  Pre-Header: Forgot password? 
                                                            </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                               <td height="50" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px">&nbsp;
                                                               </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                         </table>
                                                      </td>
                                                   </tr>
                                                </table>
                                             </td>
                                             <td width="3%" align="left" class="mob_width_15"></td>
                                          </tr>
                                       </table>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>
                                       <table width="100%" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                          <tbody>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td height="10" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px">&nbsp;</td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td align="center">
                                                   <img src="[DomainURL]/-/media/Project/EyecareFAD/Logo/email-header-logo.png"
                                                      class="center_img" alt="logo" width="129" style="display:block;outline:0;border:0;">
                                                </td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td height="10" width="100%"
                                                   style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; border-bottom:1px solid #2b5795;">
                                                   &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                       </table>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>
                                       <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="background-color:#f2f7fc;">
                                          <tbody>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td width="25%" align="left" class="mob_width_5"></td>
                                                <td width="50%" align="left" class="mob_width_95">
                                                   <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                      <tbody>
                                                         <tr>
                                                            <td height="35" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px">&nbsp;</td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                         <tr>
                                                            <td
                                                               style="color:#565656;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:18px;text-align:left;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;mso-line-height-alt:18px;">
                                                               Hello [FirstName],
                                                            </td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                         <tr>
                                                            <td height="25" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px">&nbsp;</td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                         <tr>
                                                            <td
                                                               style="color:#565656;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:18px;text-align:left;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;mso-line-height-alt:18px;">
                                                               A request to change your Find-A-Doctor account password has been received. If you
                                                               would like to reset your password, click the button below. 
                                                            </td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                         <tr>
                                                            <td height="45" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px">&nbsp;</td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                         <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                               <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                                  <tbody>
                                                                     <tr>
                                                                        <td width="20%" align="left"></td>
                                                                        <td width="60%" align="center">
                                                                           <a class="reset-btnn" href="[DomainURL]/resetpassword?[Token]"
                                                                              target="_blank">
                                                                           <img src="[DomainURL]/-/media/Project/EyecareFAD/Images/reset-password.png"
                                                                              alt="Reset password button" class="center_img" width="140"
                                                                              style="display:block;outline:0;border:0;">
                                                                           </a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td width="20%" align="left"></td>
                                                                     </tr>
                                                                  </tbody>
                                                               </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                         <tr>
                                                            <td height="45" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px">&nbsp;</td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                         <tr>
                                                            <td
                                                               style="color:#565656;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:18px;text-align:center;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;mso-line-height-alt:18px;">
                                                               If you did not 
                                                               <a href="mailto:help@eyecarefad.com"
                                                                  style="color:#2b5795; font-weight:bold;text-decoration: underline;">help@eyecarefad.com</a>.
                                                            </td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                         <tr>
                                                            <td height="70" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px">&nbsp;</td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                      </tbody>
                                                   </table>
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="25%" align="left" class="mob_width_5"></td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                       </table>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>
                                       <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="background-color:#2b5795;">
                                          <tbody>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td width="5%" align="left" class="mob_width_15"></td>
                                                <td width="90%" align="left" class="mob_width_70">
                                                   <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                      <tbody>
                                                         <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                               <table width="20%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left"
                                                                  class="mobscale">
                                                                  <tbody>
                                                                     <tr>
                                                                        <td height="40" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                     </tr>
                                                                     <tr align="center">
                                                                        <td align="center"><img
                                                                           src="[DomainURL]/-/media/Project/EyecareFAD/Logo/email-footer-small-logo.png"
                                                                           alt="Footer logo" class="center_img"
                                                                           style="display:block;outline:0;border:0;width:104px;">
                                                                        </td>
                                                                     </tr>
                                                                  </tbody>
                                                               </table>
                                                               <table width="75%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="right"
                                                                  class="mobscale">
                                                                  <tbody>
                                                                     <tr>
                                                                        <td height="40" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                     </tr>
                                                                     <tr>
                                                                        <td
                                                                           style="color:#ffffff;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:10px;line-height:18px;text-align:left;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;mso-line-height-alt:18px;"
                                                                           class="mobtxtcenter">Please review
                                                                           <a href="https://www.allergan.com/privacy-and-terms" target="_blank"
                                                                              style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration: underline;">Privacy
                                                                           statement</a> and
                                                                           <a href="https://www.allergan.com/privacy-and-terms/ccpa" target="_blank"
                                                                              style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration: underline;">California Privacy
                                                                           Policy</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                     </tr>
                                                                     <tr>
                                                                        <td height="15" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                     </tr>
                                                                     <tr>
                                                                        <td
                                                                           style="color:#ffffff;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:10px;line-height:18px;text-align:left;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;mso-line-height-alt:18px;"
                                                                           class="mobtxtcenter">©2020 AbbVie. All rights
                                                                           reserved. All trademarks are the property of their
                                                                           respective owners.
                                                                           RES‌1‌4‌1‌1‌6‌0
                                                                           1‌1‌/‌2‌0‌
                                                                        </td>
                                                                     </tr>
                                                                     <tr>
                                                                        <td height="45" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                     </tr>
                                                                  </tbody>
                                                               </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                      </tbody>
                                                   </table>
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="5%" align="left" class="mob_width_15"></td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                       </table>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                              </tbody>
                           </table>
                           <!--[if (gte mso 9)]>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
                  <![endif]-->
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
```

Comment: please check source code updated in Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mr4gbyn6/

Comment: Please, anyone, help me to resolve the issues on gmail

Comment: Updated code in question, please check

Comment: please, anyone, check the code to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

As I have said two previous times in comments, which I am now deleting, your style sheet is being stripped out of Gmail because it is malformed. If Gmail reads a bad css class, it removes the style sheet.

Many of your classes are missing `;`. An example would be line 132:

```
     .mobtxtjustify {
       text-align: justify !important
     }
```

That line should read:

```
     .mobtxtjustify {
       text-align: justify !important;
     }
```

Your HTML structure is broken as well. You have a closing tag  on line 257 does not match open tag  on line 253, which is a good indication you have more errors.

I suggest you employ a code checker to clean up your HTML as well. You could be well on your way to a fix if you had followed the same advice I offered in the comments seven hours ago.

Good luck.